# Exception at glTexImage2D() with an cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I try to load an cv::Mat into an OGL texture. The code did work. Then I tried the same code fragment (where the texture is loaded) in another project. Since then it won't work anymore.

I get the following exception by running the code at the glTexImage2D() call.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x518F4290 (atioglxx.dll) in InputFromCamWithOGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x08A3FFFC.
```

This is the code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

cv::VideoCapture capture0;
cv::VideoCapture capture1;

void captureFromWebcam(cv::Mat &frame, cv::VideoCapture &capture)
{
    capture.read(frame);
}

bool initializeCapturing()
{
    capture0.open(0);
    capture1.open(1);

    if(!capture0.isOpened() | !capture1.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Ein oder mehrere VideoCaptures konnten nicht geöffnet werden" << std::endl;

        if(!capture0.isOpened())
            capture0.release(); 
        if(!capture1.isOpened())
            capture1.release();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void releaseCapturing()
{
    capture0.release();
    capture1.release();
}




int main ()
{
    int w = 800,h=600;

    glfwInit();

    //configure glfw 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);


    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(w, h, "OpenGL", NULL, nullptr); // windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    initializeCapturing();

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // An array of 3 vectors which represents 3 vertices (singular: vertex -> ein Punkt im dreidimensionalen raum)
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        //x,y,z
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, //unten links
       1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, //unten rechts
       0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //mittig oben
    };

    // This will identify our vertex buffer
    GLuint vertexbuffer;

    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

    //was passiert wenn die texture koordinaten außerhalb des bereichs sind?
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    //was passiert wenn die textur gestreckt/gestaucht wird?
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    cv::Mat frame;
    captureFromWebcam(frame,capture0);
    //Thats the point where i get the exception
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,frame.size().width,frame.size().height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,frame.data);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
           0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
           3,                  // size
           GL_FLOAT,           // type
           GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
           0,                  // stride
           (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }


    releaseCapturing();
    glfwTerminate();

    return 1;
}
```

But the following code doesn't throw an exception:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

cv::VideoCapture capture0;
cv::VideoCapture capture1;

void captureFromWebcam(cv::Mat &frame, cv::VideoCapture &capture)
{
    capture.read(frame);
}

bool initializeCapturing()
{
    capture0.open(0);
    capture1.open(1);

    if(!capture0.isOpened() | !capture1.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Ein oder mehrere VideoCaptures konnten nicht geöffnet werden" << std::endl;

        if(!capture0.isOpened())
            capture0.release(); 
        if(!capture1.isOpened())
            capture1.release();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void releaseCapturing()
{
    capture0.release();
    capture1.release();
}

int main ()
{
    initializeCapturing();
    GLuint tex;
        glGenTextures(1, &tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        //was passiert wenn die texture koordinaten außerhalb des bereichs sind?
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        //was passiert wenn die textur gestreckt/gestaucht wird?
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        cv::Mat frame;
        captureFromWebcam(frame,capture0);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,frame.size().width,frame.size().height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,frame.data);
    releaseCapturing();
    return 1;
}
```

I've no hint of an idea anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

---UPDATE---

Since the second code doesn't make sense, I've another example that does work. I know it is some old fashioned code but I think that shouldn't matter.

```
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
    const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

    int tex;

    int loadTexture(){
        cv::Mat frame;
        captureFromWebcam(frame,capture0);
        GLuint object;
        glGenTextures(1,&object);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,object);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,frame.size().width,frame.size().height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,frame.data);
        return object;
    }
    void init(){
        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0,800,600,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        tex = loadTexture();
    }
    void draw(){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(0,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f(500,0);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(500,500);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex2f(0,500);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }

void showImage_online_sample()
{
        //initialisiere glfw
    glfwInit();

    //konfiguriere glfw (immer gleich)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    //die größe des Fensters ist nicht änderbar
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);


    //erzeuge ein Fenster
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, nullptr); // windowed

    //erzeuge den openGL context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //nötig. erlaubt die anpassung an unterschiedliche Systeme
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    initializeCapturing();

        init();
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

            draw();
           glfwPollEvents();

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
           glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
        }
        glfwTerminate();
        releaseCapturing();
        return;

}
```

Comment: Well, the second variant of the code does not make sense. Every single gl call in that will just produce an error, since you don't have a GL context. My guess would be that `frame.data` is not in the format you might assume it is (also accounting for OpenGL's default alingment setting), which of course will not matter in the second variant, since the data isn't even accessed at all there.

Comment: Ok well I didn't know that the sceond code doesn't work at all. But the problem remains. The first code did work, now it doesn't. The line with glTexImage2D is also used in other projekts with an cv::Mat and it works! In that other project the context is generated in the same way and also the TexParameters are the same.  I'll add that working project into my post.

Comment: `cv::Mat` is just an abstraction of some n-dimensional array of more or less arbitrary data types, so it can contain virtually anything. I'm not famliliar with OpenCV's image capture functionality. A quick look into the documentation did not reveal what format it will default to if you don't explicitely set the `CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT` property, so it is totally unclear to me of what format your matrix actually have.

Comment: In this case is not GL_RGBA the right input type it's GL_RGB